# how would i compare odd numbers in a sequence in python code?

Tags: python

I need to write a code that counts the number of pairs of adjacent odd numbers in a series of numbers entered by the user.

Say, for example, the user enters the series 3, 4, 5, 11, 6, 17, 9, 13, 12. There are three pairs of adjacent odd numbers: (5, 11), (17, 9), (9, 13).

here is an example of the expected input and output:

```
Enter the length of the sequence:

5

Enter number 1:

57

Enter number 2:

89

Enter number 3:

3

Enter number 4:

11

Enter number 5:

8

The number of pairs of adjacent odd numbers is: 3
```

here is the begining of my code (however i am not sure how i would find odd numbers):

```
n = eval(input("Enter the length of the sequence: \n"))
string = ""
c = 0
for i in range(n):
```

Comment: The numbers you have provided are not adjacent odd numbers. Also you can take advantage of the modulus operator % as it gives the remainder. You just need to check if the remainder is 1 when divided by 2

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are using `eval` here or storing the inputs in a string as opposed to a list... The standard way to find out if a number is odd is to use the modulo operator `%` - an int n is odd if `n % 2 != 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
n = int(input("Enter the length of the sequence: "))
numbers = []
for _ in range(n):
    numbers.append(int(input()))

c = 0
for i, j in zip(numbers, numbers[1:]):
    if i % 2 and j % 2:
        c += 1
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a % the modulus operator for finding odd numbers

```
x=int(input("Enter the number of numbers: "))
odd_l=[]
for i in range(1,x+1):
    y=int(input(f"Enter {i} number: "))
    if y%2==1:
        odd_l.append(y)
print("The number of odd number pairs is ",len(odd_l)//2)
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for a sequence like 3, 5, 7. This gives 1 but I assume that there are two pairs (3, 5) and (5, 7).

Comment: I thought that if a user inputs a number of number of times then it doesn't form a pair so I used floor division